# timestamp is not inserted in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, sql-insert

I have the following table structure:

```
recid                   int(11) 
userid                  int(11)
reset_requested_on      timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
valid_until             timestamp
sessionid               varchar(255)
```

When i print_r my array i have this data:

```
    Array
(
    [userid] => 428
    [reset_requested_on] => 1361961459
    [valid_until] => 1362134259
    [sessionid] => b6d444e0ea14768a724308fd1aa64b6d
)
```

When i perform the insert, only the recid, user id and sessionid are inserted while the timestamp fields are empty. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

EDIT:

WHEN I ADD MANUALLY THE RECORD, IF I SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME IN THE TIME STAMP FIELD, I GET THE RECORD INSERTED PROPERLY.

Anyone know how can i set up this option to be default in the table?

Regards,Zoran

Comment: We can't tell what you are doing wrong unless you show the code that inserts and the code that selects from the table.

Comment: `Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?` Yes, you missed to post the code.

Comment: Since the record is partially inserted, i doubt that code is the problem. When i try to insert the record manually, i get out of range error for both timestamp fields.

Comment: Have you tried to insert in phpmyadmin to see if there are notices (ini_set('mysql.trace_mode', 1))

Comment: Please ready my last edit, it may help.

Comment: Please post your insert code..

Comment: *i doubt that code is the problem* - So what's your hypothesis, that MySQL does not allow to insert data in `timestamp` columns and you're the first one to notice?

Comment: No, i doubted that i use wrong field, and it cross my mind that maybe i should use datetime or something else. i have no illusions whatsoever of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed passing a date instead of the seconds?

Basically, either use FROM_UNIXTIME(1362134259) on MySQL or strtotime("Y-m-d H:i:s",1362134259) on php.

Im not too familiar with codeigniter, but i assume something like:

```
$data = array(
   'userid' => 428,
   'reset_requested_on' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
   'valid_until' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
   'sessionid' => 'b6d444e0ea14768a724308fd1aa64b6d'
);
```

should work perfectly.

The major diference between timestamp and datetime is how the data is saved internally. Timestamp fields are saved as the number of seconds since the Unix epoch stored as a 32 bit integer (as a result it is vulnerable to the y2k38 bug), while datetime fields are saved with a known format to represent a date. Mathematical operations are more expensive for datetime fields than timestamp fields, but from a "clients" point of view, and unless you are using dates later than the year 2038, they are mostly the same.

So the query that leaves your PHP and enters your MySQL should have dates in an expected format, like "Y-m-d H:i:s".

Comment: i get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 inserted

Comment: should i change the fileds in the dable to datetime?

Comment: Dude, just add the insert query to your question ;)

Comment: Not that easy. I use codeigniter, which mean i have to post code from controller, then code from the model, then code from my_model, since model extents my_model....

Comment: it worked after i change the field in datetime. i use $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",now()); and now insert works as it should. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with more data to try to clarify the problem, but a more indepth answer might be of use to you

Answer (score 0):

did u missed quotes (") for the timestamp when u insert ?

```
"1362134259"
```

i m not sure. try this way.

```
$newdata = array('userid' => $data['userid'],
                 'reset_requested_on' => "$timestamp",
                 'valid_until' => "$new_timestamp",
                 'sessionid' => $this->session->userdata('session_id'));
```

Comment: $newdata = array(
                        'userid'             => $data['userid'],
                        'reset_requested_on' => $timestamp,    
                        'valid_until'        => $new_timestamp,
                        'sessionid'          => $this->session->userdata('session_id')
                   
                );